# Populate DTO from several queries

Tags: oracle, nhibernate, criteria, dto

I have a DTO with 40+ properties. But in order to populate all properties I need to execute 4 separate queries. My first query is in charged of getting basic information. For each row returned I run 3 more queries based on the id's given from the main query (N+1 problem). I can set use eager loading but then I'm loading thousands of objects that I don't need.

Should I split my DTO and create a separate DTO for each query I run then link then tie them all together into a central DTO by id?

I was envisioning a final DTO like this.

```
public class FooDto
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }
    public FirstDto FirstQueryResults { get; set; }
    public SecondDto SecondQueryResults { get; set; }
    public ThirdDto ThirdQueryResults { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a better way of solving this? I'm using Oracle and NHibernate doesn't support multi criterias. Note that I am joining most of my data. The problem comes when I need to query data with a complete new set of criteria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about creating a VIEW that joins the data to give the 40 properties all in one go, and basing your DTO on that - whatever a DTO may be ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't create a view because the database is read-only. :(

Comment: That's OK, you (or perhaps rather, the DBA) can create a view in another schema that selects (reads) data from those tables.

Comment: No dice. We are not allowed to create anything on that database regardless of schema.

Comment: This is why ORMs like nhibernate get such a bad name: trying to join data from several tables without actually joining in SQL is crazy.  Can't you just write the SQL you need and run that through nhibernate?

Comment: I don't follow "trying to join data from several tables without actually joining in SQL is crazy".

Comment: Well, you said that you need to execute 4 separate queries to obtain all the data for one DTO, which I assume is like an "entity" or "object".  Presumably that's because the data is held in various tables.  You could get it all in 1 query if you could perform a SQL join: "select a.xxx, b.xxx, ... from a join b...".  That is a far better idea than running lots of tiny queries and joining the data together in the application - for a start it is 1 round trip to the database rather than 4.  That's what I meant.

Comment: For the most part everything is joined. The problem comes when I need to query tables that use totally different criterias.